# Delete Paragraphs Not Containing Country Name in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to delete paragraphs in Word document not containing the name of the country I am interested in.  Based on the answer to another question on this site, I came up with:

```
Sub DeleteParagraphContainingString()

    Dim search As String
    search = "Afghan"

    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        Dim txt As String
        txt = para.Range.Text

        If Not InStr(LCase(txt), search) Then
            para.Range.Delete
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

However, this deletes EVERY paragraph in the document.  Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks!  I do not know much about Word macros, as may be obvious from this question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the value you are searching for, "Afghan," has a capital 'A' in it, but you have changed the paragraph text to all lowercase.  Change the value you are searching for to "afghan" with a lowercase 'a' and it should work.

Comment: In addition, OP may need `InStr(LCase(txt), search) > 0`.

Comment: Thanks so much to you both!  Changing the case alone did not fix it, but it worked after I changed the case and replaced InStr(LCase(txt), search) with InStr(LCase(txt), search) > 0.